# cx_Oracle connect to Oracle Connection Manager without tnsnames.ora file

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I need to connect to Oracle via OCM a non OCM connection looks to be simple

```
conn_str = 'user/password@host:port/service_name'

# oracle connection
self.con = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
```

same can be translated to this when using tnsnames.ora

```
db_alias = 
       (DESCRIPTION=               
           ) 
           (ADDRESS= 
              (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DatabaseHost)(PORT=DatabasePort) 
           ) 
           (CONNECT_DATA= 
              (SERVICE_NAME=DatabaseService)
           ) 
       )
```

when we connect to OCM using tnsnames.ora, the following is added

```
db_alias = 
   (DESCRIPTION= 
          ***(SOURCE_ROUTE=YES)
          (ADDRESS= 
              (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=ConnectionManagerHost)(PORT=ConnectionManagerPort)***
       ) 
       (ADDRESS= 
          (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DatabaseHost)(PORT=DatabasePort) 
       ) 
       (CONNECT_DATA= 
          (SERVICE_NAME=DatabaseService)
       ) 
   )
```

how do we do the same in python with cx_Oracle?

Answer (score 5):

[Update: cx_Oracle was renamed to [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/). See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) - use this version instead of cx_Oracle.  Also the old `makedsn()` function was obsoleted by the [ConnectParams](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connect_param.html) object.]

Use the TNS alias in the connection string:

```
conn_str = 'chris/mypassword@db_alias'  # use the entry from the tnsnames.ora file
self.con = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
```

or use the alias with the other form of `connect()` like this:

```
self.con = cx_Oracle.connect(user='chris', password='mypassword', dsn='db_alias')
```

If you know the actual connect descriptor then you could do:

```
cs = """(DESCRIPTION=
             (FAILOVER=on)
             (ADDRESS_LIST=
               (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sales1-svr)(PORT=1521))
               (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sales2-svr)(PORT=1521)))
             (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sales.example.com)))"""

self.con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="chris", password='mypassword', dsn=cs)
```

See [Connection Strings](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The point is not to use tnsnames.ora alias. Is there any way of constructing some smart query string, or passing some parameters to cx_Oracle connect method?

Comment: You can pass the full string in the place of db_alias and not have it stored in tnsnames.ora. There is no way to handle the creation of that string besides makedsn() -- and that doesn't handle the addition of (SOURCE_ROUTE=YES).

Comment: An example (with Node.js, but it's similar for Python) is at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#embedtns

Comment: Thank you for the answers, it worked for me. Also will be nice to update the tutorial https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial

Comment: My man! I didn't realize the db_alias from your tnsnames.ora works. Was difficult trying to format the DNS since my DBA created something pretty complex. Awesome, appreciate it. Also worthwhile noting that you need to have all your Oracle Environmental Variables set properly, i.e., ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/full_or_instant_oracle_client, TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib (full client) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME (instant client); you need your tsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files placed in your $TNS_ADMIN. Also works for generating the slqalchemy engine too

Comment: Environment settings are definitely important.  Some notes: never set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client. And there's no need to set TNS_ADMIN if your files are already in the /network/admin directory of your installation; that's a default directory.  Also, if you install the Instant Client RPMs you don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH since the RPMs configure & run `ldconfig`.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward command would be the following:

```
import cx_Oracle
# Make DSN address. Real values for host address, port and service name were replaced by '<>'.
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('<host_address>', '<port>', service_name='<service_name>')

# Connect to DSN
orcl = cx_Oracle.connect(user='<username>', password='<password>', dsn=dsn)
```